# AWK - transmission variable assigned in the 'BEGIN' to 'date'?

Tags: awk

Please help this problem.

I would like to assigned variable (a="echo 2012-03-16") in the 'BEGIN' to the command 'date'. The 'date' to getline and print '$0'.

Here's an example:

```
awk 'BEGIN {a="echo 2012-03-16"; "date +%s -d "$a" " | getline; print $0}'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can reference variable `a` directly in `awk`, `$` is not needed.
- `date +%s -d 2012-03-16` is sent to shell, `echo` is not needed.

---

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {a="2012-03-16"; "date +%s -d "a | getline; print $0}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but not the point. I want to insert the date that is in the variable 'a ="2010-03-29"'. date +%s -d 2010-03-29 --> 1269813600 In this way, print the current date. awk 'BEGIN {a="2010-03-29"; "date +%s -d a" | getline; print $0}' --> 1331859600

Comment: Kev's answer looks right to me. You'll help yourself get a faster and better answer if you edit your question to include your required output. Are you saying that you have a var '${a}' that is in your shell environment? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. This is a good thing that they just will not work on Ubuntu 10.10.###

$ awk 'BEGIN {a="2010-03-29", "date +%s-d "a | getline; print $0}'
-->/ bin / sh: 2010-03-29: not found  ###

Ubuntu 10.04 works well.

pc: ~ $ awk 'BEGIN {a="2010-03-29", "date +%s-d "a | getline; print $0}'
-->1269813600

### Thank you for your help.